# Run PyTorch within QGIS Plugin using PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I would like to run my object detection module (programmed in PyTorch) in a QGIS plugin. Currently, I have implemented all the required functionality in the QGIS plugin (getting the image, selecting a region on interest (RoI), labeling objects, ...) and I have implemented the detection module. **However, I am unsure how to combine the two modules, as my detection module requires specific python libraries which are not part of the QGIS environment and I am not sure if it is the best idea to just install them into the QGIS environment.**

My first idea would be this workflow:
QGIS Plugin --> Saves image, RoI and labels to disk; Python Plugin --> Loads image, RoI and labels from disk --> Processes everything --> Saves results to disk again; QGIS Plugin --> Loads results

**However, this looks horribly complicated and slow to me.**

My second idea was to just install all the python dependencies into the QGIS environment. **However, I am unsure if this could brick QGIS and furthermore, even if it doesn't right now, it may in the future.**

How would you recommend that I implement my plugin?